# Pass variable to GraphQL using python module graphqlclient

Tags: python, graphql

I am trying to fetch somw data from a API + graphQL server. [Here](http://open-targets-genetics.appspot.com/graphql/schema) you can see the scheme. [Here](http://open-targets-genetics.appspot.com/graphql) the endpoint.
I am using python 2.7.5 qith a module called [graphqlclient](https://github.com/prisma/python-graphql-client) 
This is the script I wrote:

```
from graphqlclient import GraphQLClient 
client = GraphQLClient('http://genetics-api.opentargets.io/graphql')
result = client.execute('''
query {
manhattan(
studyId: "GCST004599"
pageIndex: 0
pageSize: 10000
){associations
{variant {
rsId
altAllele
refAllele
nearestGene {
id}nearestCodingGene {
id}}pval
bestGenes{
gene {
id
}score}
credibleSetSize
ldSetSize
}}}''')
print(result)
```

So far it is working and I am getting what I was expecting. However, I want too use a set of different values for "studyID" and I can't set a variable. Do you have experience with this module or any other suggestions?

Comment: It's an extremely simple package; I'd suggest clicking on the GitHub link you provide, the directory `graphqlclient`, and the source file `client.py` to see if there are any hints there.

Comment: There is this function which looks like I can use variable. But using this grammar is not working

 `def _send(self, query, variables):` 
        `data = {'query': query,`
                `'variables': variables}`

Answer (score 0):

Example code from: https://github.com/prodigyeducation/python-graphql-client

```py
client = GraphqlClient(endpoint="https://countries.trevorblades.com")
query = """
    query countryQuery($countryCode: String) {
        country(code:$countryCode) {
            code
            name
        }
    }
"""
variables = {"countryCode": "CA"}
data = client.execute(query=query, variables=variables)
```

This works ok as expected.

### Your code (updated with current endpoint URL)

```py
from python_graphql_client import GraphqlClient

client = GraphqlClient('https://api.genetics.opentargets.org/graphql')
result = client.execute('''
query {
  manhattan(studyId: "GCST004599", pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10000) {
    associations {
      variant {
        rsId
        altAllele
        refAllele
        nearestGene {
          id
        }
        nearestCodingGene {
          id
        }
      }
      pval
      bestGenes {
        gene {
          id
        }
        score
      }
      credibleSetSize
      ldSetSize
    }
  }
}
''')
print(result)
```

If you're tweaking your query string, you're doing it wrong! Use variables instead. That's how GraphQL was designed to be used.

### Proper pythonic way

```py
result = client.execute('''
query associationsQuery($id: String) {
  manhattan(studyId: $id, pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10000) {
    associations {
      variant {
        rsId
        altAllele
        refAllele
        nearestGene {
          id
        }
        nearestCodingGene {
          id
        }
      }
      pval
      bestGenes {
        gene {
          id
        }
        score
      }
      credibleSetSize
      ldSetSize
    }
  }
}
''', variables={id: "GCST004599"})
```

Now the approach is clean, human-readable and doesn't involve any Python string-mangling.